# Video Restarts on orientation change

Tags: android, video, rotation

I wrote a code to play a video from my site.

It works correctly but when I rotate my phone the video restarts from the start.

How do I solve this?

```
public class ActivityVideoDetail extends Activity {

    private VideoDetail videoDetail;
    private TextView    txtResult;
    // -------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_activity_video_detail);
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {

        }
        else {
            ini();
        }
    }


    // -------------------------
    private void ini() {
        videoDetail = (VideoDetail) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable(VideoDetail.VIDEO_DETAIL);
        txtResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
        txtResult.setText(videoDetail.getVideoTitle());

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoDetail.getVideoPath());
        //   Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://daily3gp.com/vids/747.3gp");

        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);

        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: this problem is happening because when orientation get changes it automatically refreshes your code i mean it call onCreate method thats why this thing is happening with your code please go through my answer hop it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Add

**android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"**

in your Manifest file
inside the

`<activity>` tag

Answer (score 0):

When you rotate the screen onCreate method is called again.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8GHs.png

Add this flag to your manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```